# Closeness of set for not everywhere continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have a function $w:\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $w(x)\in[0,2\pi)$. I am also given for free that $w$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(x_1,0)\mid x_1\ge0\}$.

I would like to show that the set $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid w(x) \in [\theta,\eta]\}$ for some $0\le\theta\le\eta<2\pi$ is closed.

This is what I've done so far:

We can express A as
$A=\{x^2\in\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash\{x_1,0\mid x_1\ge0\}\mid w(x) \in [\theta,\eta]\}\cup\{x^2\in\{x_1,0\mid x_1\ge0\} \mid w(x) \in [\theta,\eta]\}$

where the first part is of course closed due to continuity. I now want to show that the 2nd part is also closed. So how should I do that? also, is the following true since $w$ isn't defined on {0}?

$\{x^2\in\{x_1,0\mid x_1\ge0\} \mid w(x) \in [\theta,\eta]\}=\{x^2\in\{x_1,0\mid x_1>0\} \mid w(x) \in [\theta,\eta]\}$

Maybe it's all wrong. Could use any help :)

Edit: The function $w(x)$ is the angle function in the counter clock wise direction given by the unique solution to the equations:

$\frac{x_1}{∣∣x∣∣_2}=cos(w)$ and $\frac{x_2}{∣∣x∣∣_2}=sin(w)$

Edit 2:

But I'm not trying to use the continuity of w of the whole plane(without the origo). I'm seeing w more as a piecewise function like this: $$
   w(x) = \left\{
     \begin{cases}
       \tilde{w}(x) & : x \in \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(x_1,0)\mid x_1\ge 0\}\\
       \arctan (y/x) & : x \in \{(x_1,0)\mid x_1 > 0\}
     \end{cases}
   \right.$$
where the 2nd argument is just 0 all the way.

So when we take the preimage of $[\theta,\eta]$ for $\theta=0$ we will have the positive x-axis plus whatever $\tilde{w}^{-1}[\theta,\eta]$ is. We will also never have to approach y from below since $w$ maps to $[0,2\pi)$.

am I wrong?

Comment: Let $w(q, 0) = 1$ when $q>0$ is rational and let $w(x, y) = 0$ otherwise. Seems to be an obvious counterexample. Am I missing something?

Comment: You mean the premise that A is closed is not necessarily true? What if the function w is given implicitly as the solution to the two equations below?

Comment: You mean, **"The angle function w given by the solution to ..."**? Would you add that to the question? It's kind of important.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė yes of course, it's there now.

Comment: Can you see the shape of the preimage of $w$? Could you draw  the set $w^{-1}([\pi/4, \pi/2])$ on paper, for example?

Comment: Frankly I can't. What exactly is $w(x)$ given by?

Comment: Preimage of $w$ is a slice of pizza. Or the area between two rays. Not sure how the shape is called properly. You really need to play around with the function if you have no idea what it looks like...

Comment: I know exactly what you are talking about. It's like an arc segment. There are additional contrain on the set A which is the length of the vectors that I did not include here. However, even with image in my head I'm still not sure how exacly to prove it. or even how the function w(x) is expressed.

Comment: $w$ can be written as [arg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29).

Comment: for one, $\arctan(y/x)$ isn't $w$ because $\arctan(\frac {-1} {-1}) = \arctan(\frac 1 1)$ but $w(-1, -1) \neq w(1, 1)$. There is a reason why wikipedia gives 6 cases in the expression of arg. Secondly, you're looking at $\arctan(y/x)$ on $y = 0$ so that $\arctan(0/x) = 0$  - did you mix up the conditions? And what is $\tilde{w}$ anyway? The fact that $w$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{(x, 0)|x > 0\}$ is not sufficient. By the way, you are welcome to edit the whole question. It's not so clear to me what you are currently asking about.

Comment: I know arctan isn't w everywhere. The counter exemple you have isn't a point on the positive x-axis, which is where I had my arctan defined on. I'm not sure how I had my conditions mixed up though? the positive x-axis has y=0. the tilde on w is just to differentiate it from the w on the positive x-axis.

Comment: I assumed that you mixed up the conditions because with the conditions you have, $\arctan(y/x) = 0$. Why then would you write $\arctan$ instead of $0$?

Comment: Oh, well I wrote that just to show how one would get 0. I can change to 0. but even then the method still can't be used?

Comment: You already had $\tilde{w}(x_1, 0) = 0$ so I don't see the point. Again, the given continuity condition is not enough. You will have to think of $w$ as the angle function.

Comment: Now I feel like I'm at a dead end. I want to show that the set A is closed, but without using arg. As elegant as arg might be, it's out of my course of study. I'm trying to appeal to the fact that I'm given the continuity condition(use without proof) and the fact that w is given by the solution to the two equations involving cos and sin. So I believe that those are the tools(or part of) to show the closeness of the set. Can that be achieved?

Comment: Well, considering that the given equations define arg, you'll have a hard time not using it. But Henning Makholm comes as close to not using it as you can...

Comment: Al right, thanks for the help. I'll think about everything that's been said here.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė just out of curiosity, how do you even obtain arg from those equations?

Comment: Any point $(x_1, x_2)$ can be written as $(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ with $r = ||x||$. Then, clearly, $x_1/||x|| = r \cos \theta / r = \cos \theta$. It really just boils down to having a way to convert polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. In polar coordinates arg is just $(\theta, r) \mapsto \theta$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessarily true. For example, consider
$$ w(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{when }(x,y)=(1,0) \\ 3& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
This is continuous everywhere except on the positive $x$-axis, yet $w^{-1}([2,4])$ is not closed.

Perhaps you meant to prove this specifically for the function that returns the direction angle of the input vector?

---

**Specifically for the angle function.** I've tried to find something slick, but it looks like the easiest way out would be to show directly from the definition that the *complement* of the set is *open*.

Therefore, let's look at some point $P=r(\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$ with $r>0$ and either $0\le phi<\theta$ or $\eta<\phi<2\pi$. We must show that there's a ball around $P$ that is disjoing from $A$.

In the case $0<\phi<\theta$, let $\epsilon = \min(\theta-\phi, \phi, \pi/4)$, and consider the open ball $B_{r\sin\epsilon}(P)$. A bit of plane trigonometry shows that every point in this ball has $w$ in the interval $(\phi-\epsilon,\phi+\epsilon)$ and is therefore outside $A$.

In the case $\eta<\phi<2\pi$, let $\epsilon = \min(2\pi-\phi, \phi-\eta, \pi/2)$, and consider the open ball $B_{r\sin\epsilon}(P)$. As before, trigonometry shows that every point in this ball has $w$ in the interval $(\phi-\epsilon,\phi+\epsilon)$ and is therefore outside $A$.

In the case $\phi = 0$ let $\epsilon = \min(\theta,2\pi-\eta,\pi/4$ and again consider $B_{\r\sin\epsilon}(P)$. Points in this ball have $w$ in $[0,\epsilon)$ (when they are on or above the $x$-axis) or in $(2\pi-\epsilon, 2\pi)$ (otherwise), and in either case the point outside $A$.

Comment: That is right. The angle function $w$ given by the solution to $\frac{x_1}{||x||_2}=cos(w)$ and $\frac{x_2}{||x||_2}=sin(w)$

Comment: so how exactly do I prove this? what makes w(x) special? I couldn't obtain anything useful by solving the equations.

Comment: I think I found something useful now, assuming the equality I have at the end there is true. If I solve the equations, I get w(x)=tan^{-1}(x_2/x_1) for x_1 not 0, and for all {x_1,0∣ x_1 >0} it would simply be {0}, so it's continuous? does that make sense at all?

Comment: @ChuckP: Your arctangent formula is not exactly true, because it would give the same result for $(-1,-1)$ as for $(1,1)$. Let me add a sketch for the angle case.

Comment: @ChuckP: I've sketched a sort of brute-force argument that should work for the angle function. How to fill in the details would depend on how exactly your trig functions are defined and how much geometric intuition you're allowed to appeal to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It might be a little too geometric for me xd, I'll try to chew on it and maybe it will shed some light to me later. however is there a way to show it using continuity, since I figure the professor wouldn't be giving us that continuity if it shouldn't be used. Also, how would w(x) look like if mine was off?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f (\rho, r) = (r\cos \rho, r\sin \rho, \rho)$ map polar coordinate space $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^+$ to a surface in $\mathbb R^3$. Observe that for $0 \leq z < 2\pi$, this surface is the graph of $w$, namely, that if we take $x = r\cos \rho, y = r\sin \rho, w = \rho$ then $||\vec{x}|| = r$ and $\frac x {||\vec{x}||} = \cos w$, same for $y$.

Intersect this surface with the set $\{(x, y, z) | z\in[\theta, \eta] \}$. Then project the first two coordinates with $p_{1,2}(x, y, z) = (x, y)$. You get $A$. Because continuous images and intersections of closed sets are closed, we end up with $A$ closed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the link for arg and cover space now as it's the first time for me hear about them. I do wonder though, since both your solution and Henning's are more elaborated than I had expected, so if you could tell me why I'm wrong in my thinking, that's be awesome: Since we have the continuity for w on the entire R^2 plan except for the positive x axis, and the function isn't defined on 0, what we have left is just x>0, in which case w(x) can be expressed as arctan(y/x)(based on [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29#Computation)), which is continuous

Comment: To use the continuity of $w$, you need to show that when you  approach any point $y = 0$ from below, you have $w(x, y) > \eta$. In other words, that the preimage of $[\theta, \eta]$ is not concerned with what happens around $y = 0$. I'm not sure how to show this in a simple way.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelè: hey, I've had an edit, hopefully you can check it out.